# Warning when loading reference gene list for over representation analysis using WebGestaltR

Tags: r

I get following warning that the data length of my reference gene list does not match the number of rows, when doing an Overrepresentation analysis with a gene list and a custom reference gene list using WebGestaltR. When the reference list is loaded, following warning flashes:

```
Loading the functional categories...
Loading the ID list...
Loading the reference list...
data length [43707] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [10929]
```

I can't make sense of that warning, because when I ran the exact same analysis some weeks earlier I did not get the warning. Can I just ignore it? The code still continues executing and produces enrichment analysis results. The length of my reference gene list is 10880 lines, containing one gene ensembl ID per line. So I don't even know where the numbers in the warning message come from.

I'm using R version 3.5.1 and WebGestaltR package version 0.4.1.

When I run the analysis with the same gene lists online on http://www.webgestalt.org/,
1. no warning flashes and 
2. the results differ from the ones returned by WebGestaltR. So I'm unsure if I can trust the analysis right now.

When I paste only a small fraction of the reference genes as input the code executes without warning. So there seems to be an issue with long gene lists. Of with my gene list, but I can't figure out was has changed from two weeks before.

I appreciate any help!

```
library(WebGestaltR)

WebGestaltR(interestGeneFile= allSpecies_CorrelatingGenes_Testis.txt,
            interestGeneType="ensembl_gene_id",
            enrichMethod="ORA",
            organism="hsapiens",
enrichDatabase="geneontology_Biological_Process_noRedundant",
            referenceGeneFile=allSpecies_ReferenceGenes_Testis.txt,
            referenceGeneType="ensembl_gene_id",
            fdrMethod="BH", # Benjamini Hochberg
            sigMethod="fdr",
            fdrThr=0.01,
            isOutput=TRUE,outputDirectory="Extract_PeakGenes/Biological_Process", projectName=allSpecies)
```